# Virtual multiplication operator in c++

Tags: c++, virtual, multiplication

I have ancestor abstact class called Figure

```
class Figure {
public:
   string style, color, name;


   virtual void printInfo() = 0;
   /*
   different methods here
   */
   virtual Figure operator * (int prod) = 0;

};
```

And I have Line class (and few others) that inherites Figure.

```
class Line : public Figure {
     /* .... */
     Line operator*(int prod);
};

Line Line::operator *(int prod) {
    Line temp = *this ;
    Point p = getPoint2();
    p.setXYZ(p.getX() * prod, p.getY() * prod, p.getZ() * prod);
    temp.setPoint2(p);
    return temp;
}
```

The point is that I want to have such virtual operator, but if I write code as above I get dozen of mistakes. 
What have I done wrong?

Comment: We'll need to see what those errors are.  You have many functions there that you haven't shown the source for, so the errors could be coming from anywhere.

Comment: I mean errors connected with operator: 'error: invalid abstract return type for member function ‘virtual Figure Figure::operator*(int)’' and 'error: invalid covariant return type for ‘virtual Line Line::operator*(int)’'

Comment: @mindmaster welcome to the world of covariance, the feature which puts you within an inch of being able to do some really cool stuff, then jerks it away from you at the last second. Fred Larson's answer is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Figure` is an abstract class, so you can't return it by value. It is abstract because it has pure virtual methods. Abstract classes cannot be instantiated.

Answer (score 0):

`Figure::operator*` returns a `Figure` by value.
`Line::operator*` returns a `Line` by value.
You are only allowed to return a derived type if it's returned by pointer or reference, but *not* by value.

My code is now in that same point, but I haven't figured out how to work around this problem, other than to remove virtual functions that return by value.

Comment: I think you mean, "by pointer or reference, but not by value".

Answer (score 0):

overloading operators, such as the product operator, should be done with great care, as it is (unfortunately) easily possible to create a syntax which defies common sense. Making such overloaded operators virtual doesn't help this. (Of course your code is obviously faulty as pointed out already---neither Figure nor Line can be used as return type, for both are abstract.)

Answer (score 0):

To add to the previous answers:  if you really need operator* to be overloaded, you have to realise that you need to come up with some way of creating the new `Figure` that you will be returning.

Before you do that, however, it may be best to point out that the binary operator* should generally be overloaded outside the class like this:

```
T operator*(T const& lhs, T const& rhs);
```

It may be useful to make it a friend, but it is also often unnecessary.  If you wish for this operator to behave differently depending on whether a T or a derived-from-T was passed in, have it call a virtual `T multiply(T const& rhs) const;` function on one of the sides (this is a good idea anyway).

Now, as for the returning, there's several ways of doing this:

**Make** `Figure` **not abstract and return it by value**

This is a fairly simple solution, but unfortunately, it does little good.  Chances are, if you are using polymorphism, the slicing is unacceptable.

`new` **the** `Figure` **and return by reference**

Chances are, this would look like this:

```
T& operator*(T const& lhs, int rhs) {
    T* t = lhs.Clone(); // Clone returns a new derived-from-T.
    t->multiply(rhs);
    return *t;
}
```

This works, but it makes memory management difficult:  for one, if `multiply()` throws, you have a memory leak.  In general, while this could be done, it does not seem wise.

**Use PImpl and return the wrapper by value**

To be honest, I have no practical experience with PImpl, but I think it (or something similar) could be applied here.  Instead of passing around `Figure*`s, you could rename your current `Figure` to `FigureImpl`, and create a new `Figure` class that would read:

```
class Figure {
    // We don't want direct instantiation.
    Figure();
    Figure(FigureImpl* fi) : p_(fi) {}

  public:
    Figure(Figure const& f)
        : p_(f.p_->Clone())
    {}
    void PrintInfo(); // Hm, why not overload operator<<?
    Figure Multiply(int rhs) const {
      Figure f(p_.Clone());
      f.p_->Multiply(rhs);
      return f;
      // Or even:  return Figure(p_->Multiply(rhs.p_));
      // with Multiply returning a new FigureImpl*.
    }

  private:
    unique_ptr<FigureImpl*> p_;
};

Figure operator*(Figure const& lhs, int rhs) {
    return lhs.Multiply(rhs);
}
```

You can then have a `FigureImpl` class and a `LineImpl` class:

```
struct FigureImpl {
    virtual void printInfo() = 0;
    virtual void Multiply(int) = 0; // or make it const and return a FigureImpl*
};

struct LineImpl {
    // implement functions
};
```

There are two problems left, the main one being the instantiation of `Figure`.  I would suggest creating some function like `MakeLineFigure` that return a new `Figure` of the appropriate type.  You could also expose `FigureImpl` to the end-user, but that seems less useful.

The other problem is that you cannot make just normal `LineImpl`s any more.  Whether this is really an issue varies on how you intend to use the class.  You could make a similar wrapper called `Line` and give it an `operator Figure` (this may be nice; you don't need the instantiation functions), but it will end up being even more boilerplate (perhaps you could do it with inheritance, where all new classes do not get any new member variables, and just expand on the functions -- I haven't tried).

<s>A final problem I see, which does not depend on which route you choose, is that you are allowing a line to be multiplied by a plane.  It could be that this is the correct behaviour, but it looks questionable.</s>

I had not noticed the multiplication was with a scalar, so never mind that last part.